# Script for uninstalling GCPW from multiple systems in a corporate environment

Tags: windows, powershell, uninstall

I am looking at ways to uninstall GCPW from close to 100 systems as we are moving to Microsoft. Would running the `uninstall.exe` using a script suffice? The problem I foresee is that the `uninstall` file resides in a folder which named after the version number of the GCPW installed, which will be different for users. So, I am stuck here.

Is there a better approach to this? Basically I need mininmal end-user interaction. So, far I think a script is the best choice. Please enlighten if there is a better way.

Comment: What is the basic path with an example version number for the uninstall.exe location? This is absolutely possible and easily able to push to hundreds of machine. I do this sort of thing all the time with no problems.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I did it using `wmic` . No need for the version number. A simple batch script.